# How to trigger an action upon applying bulk edit options like edit or move to trash? Are there any specific hooks?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Upon creating, editing or deleting a new product, I'm able to delete some set of transients but couldn't get it done if it's a bulk action at the admin panel like bulk edit or move to trash.

I've used the action hook 'transition_post_status' and whenever there is a change from old status to a new status or if it's an update scenario then my transient deleting code gets executed. But this doesn't work for bulk edit or bulk move to trash.

```
function ga_delete_transients( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {//deletes transients if exists upon create,trash and update

 global $post,$wpdb;

 if ( $post->post_type !== 'product' ) return;
 if($old_status!==$new_status|| $old_status == 'publish' && $new_status =='publish'){
  $sql = "SELECT *  FROM labtag_wp.wp_labtag_options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('%\_transient\_ga_loop_products_%')";
  $ga_transient_result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
   if(!empty($ga_transient_result)){

    $wpdb->query( "DELETE   FROM labtag_wp.wp_labtag_options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('%\_transient\_ga_loop_products_%')" );
    }
 }


 }

 add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'ga_delete_transients', 10, 3 );
```

I get all the transients deleted when it's creating, updating or moving to trash for a new product but upon bulk actions, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This solution based on [Wordpress custom post action hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169376/wordpress-custom-post-action-hook?rq=1) works but isn't good in case of a bulk delete of posts as any bulk delete within my code will have $post to be null.

```
function ga_delete_transients($post) {

  global $wpdb,$post;


 if(isset($post)&&$post->post_type=='product' || !isset($post)  ) {//doesn't work in case of bulk delete of posts



  $sql = "SELECT *  FROM labtag_wp.wp_labtag_options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('%\_transient\_ga_loop_products_%')";
  $ga_transient_result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  if(!empty($ga_transient_result)){

      $wpdb->query( "DELETE   FROM labtag_wp.wp_labtag_options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('%\_transient\_ga_loop_products_%')" );
  }

 }
 else{
   return;
 }

}

$all_actions = array('save_post','wp_delete_post','wp_trash_post');

foreach ($all_actions as $current_action) {

  add_action($current_action, 'ga_delete_transients',1);
}
```